# want to send javascript code to socket.io server

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I want to send a javascript code to the socket.io server so that server broadcast to the clients and that code get executed .

what i tried i make a json variable like this .and send that via socket.io

```
 var sent={
          'code': function(){
           console.log('javascript code');
          }

        };

socket.send(sent);
```

when i check at server the message comes is `{}`  and same as it is to the other client .

what is wrong in this code , how should i send javascript code ?

Comment: JSON cannot contain functions. You would have to convert it into a string and then `eval()` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not do this. You will open all listening clients to being hacked.

*that said...*

...you could follow pimbdb and pass the function in as a string, then use `eval` on the receiving end to execute it:

```
// on the sending client
var sent = {
    "code": "function() { /* do something not evil */ }"
}
socket.send(sent);

// on the receiving client
socket.on('message', function(data) {
    if (data.code) eval(data.code); // and pray.
});
```

Again, don't. Instead, pass some non-executable data that can then be interpreted in a limited number of non-malicious ways.

EDIT: Apologies, interpreted that as if you were executing code on the server. But client<-> client is XSS-prone, still.